# Proving language is regular

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, dfa, nfa

Let Σ be a finite alphabet and L ⊆ Σ
be a language. Let Σ0 ⊆ Σ. For each string
w = w1 · · · wn ∈ Σ
, define res(w, Σ
0
) = y1 · · · yn where yi = wi
if wi ∈ Σ
0
, and yi =  if
wi ∈ Σ \ Σ
0
, for each 1 ≤ i ≤ n. (For example res(abracadabra, {a, b}) = abaaaba.) Then
define res(L, Σ
0
) = {res(w, Σ
0
) : w ∈ L}

**I have a very general direction and thought process for these problems, however, i am not completely sure i could construct a viable proof for the following problems. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.**

(a) Show that if L ⊆ Σ*
?
is regular and Σ0 ⊆ Σ, res(L, Σ
0
) must be regular.

**i know for this one, a DFA cannot be made for this language. So i will have to figure out a different way. A subset of any regular language is not necessarily regular.**

(b) Show that if L ⊆ Σ*
is context-free and Σ0 ⊆ Σ, res(L, Σ
0
) must be context-free.

**I know that for this problem, one way to solve it would be to provide a context free grammar**

(c) Show that if L ⊆ Σ*
 and res(L, Σ
0
) is regular whenever Σ0 ⊂ Σ, L need not be regular.

**For this question, we can say that even if L is not regular, that the empty language is a regular subset of this language. This would be true in all languages (whether it is regular or not)**

Comment: If you want help with your homework, at least show some evidence that you've tried and ask about specific sub-problems. Just pasting in four problems and saying "I think I have an idea, but please tell me the answer" is unlikely to attract any positive attention!

Comment: Do you really mean that L is a subset of the alphabet?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, that is what the assignment actually states.

Comment: @CS959595 It is almost certainly a typo since that would make little sense.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thats what i initially thought, however, after asking my professor, i was told it was actually intended.

Comment: @CS959595 Odd -- I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this question as well, here were my thoughts

for a:  if L is regular, it can be represented by a regular expression, so it should be possible to make a regular expression for L'.

for b: make a CFG where the terminals found in V and R of {V,E',R,S} just includes the terminals of E'

for c: assume that res(L, E') is regular, so as long as the alphabet is a true subset in that it can not equal the alphabet of L. L does not need to be regular.

These are just my initial thoughts, so take them with a grain of salt (maybe someone else can provide feedback)

Answer (score 0):

While its evident that this is a homework assignment, a suggestion for part (a) is to look into closure properties for regular languages.

Take a look at L, the provided language in res(L, Σ’). Now take a look at the language (lets call it L') over the alphabet Σ’.

Now lets look at your example:

```
res(abracadabra, {a, b}) = abaaaba
```

In this scenario, L ∈ { abracadabra } and L' ∈ { abaaaba }

Between these two languages, L and L', what standard set operation can we use to create a set of only the elements each language has in common?

If you took a look at closure properties for regular languages, I'm sure you'll see the perfect fit!